# Python3.7.3以降のTreeviewの背景色が変わらない問題の修正

Tags: python, tkinter

Python3.7.3以降バージョンにTreeviewの背景色が変わらない問題があるのですが修正方法をご存知のかたいらっしゃったらご教示いただけますか?

Comment: こちらと同件と思われます。[Python ttk.Treeview python3.7でリストに割り当てたtagに対して色を設定する方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/64095/26370)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ご提示の内容で変更できました。